# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name <

Tags: tkinter

In my MVC-Application I would like to load data from an xml file and show it in two different views in an paned window.
In the left pane I would like to display the data in a tk.ttk.Treeview.
In the right pane I would like to display the data in a tk.tkk.Canvas.

Main Application:

```
from lscController import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

Controller:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk # python 2
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import tkinter as Tk # python 3

from lscView import LSCGUI

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk.Tk()
        self.model = LSCDocument('name')
        self.view = LSCGUI(self.root, self.model)

    def run(self):
        self.root.title("MVC Charts")
        self.root.deiconify()
        self.root.mainloop(
```

file **lscTreeView.py**:

```
class LSCTree():
    def __init__(self, window,model):
        super().__init__()
        frame = tk.Frame(window)
        frame.pack()
```

I want to add the view to the left pane of the PanedWindow in the file **lscView.py**:

```
class LSCGUI():
    def __init__(self, window, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("Model")
        self.model = model
        ''' Full Screen Or not '''
        self.window.attributes('-fullscreen',False)
        self.window.geometry('800x600')


        ''' ________Frame as paned windows (left / right)________ '''
        pwstyle = tk.ttk.Style()
        pwstyle.configure('TPanedwindow ', foreground='green')
        self.frame = tk.ttk.PanedWindow(style='TPanedwindow',orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.treeview=TREE.LSCTree(self.frame,model)
        self.frame.add(self.treeview)
```

and get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "<lscTreeView.LSCTree object at 0x00000222D62B5910>"
```

VS Code says the error is here:     `self.frame.add(self.treeview)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are passing self.treeview to a function which requires a widget as an argument:

```
self.frame.add(self.treeview)
```

This is where you define self.treeview:

```
self.treeview=TREE.LSCTree(self.frame,model)
```

This is the definition of LSCTree:

```
class LSCTree():
    def __init__(self, window,model):
        ...
```

`LSCTree` is clearly not a widget. You can't add a non-widget to a panedwindow.

The best solution would be to make `LSCTree` inherit from `Frame` so that it can be treated as a widget, instead of using composition to have a frame as an attribute of `LSCTree`.

```
class LSCTree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, window,model):
        super().__init__(window)
        ...
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, ...)
        ...
```